# HighCharts. Is it possible to access Highcharts classes through a label context?

Tags: highcharts, label

Task:
I need to programmatically calculate the position of the labels relative to the labels of the chart.

Problem:
Dependence HighCharts is loaded lazily. I do not have direct access to the dependency, respectively, no access to the classes. How else can I create an object from the tick class? Is it possible to create an object through a context in the label formatting function?

[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
            var ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks,
                ticksPositions = this.xAxis[0].tickPositions,
                tick0x,
                tick1x;

            var getPosition = function (tick) {
                var axis = tick.axis;
                return Highcharts.Tick.prototype.getPosition.call(tick, axis.horiz, tick.pos, axis.tickmarkOffset);
            };

            tick0x = getPosition(ticks[ticksPositions[0]]).x;
            tick1x = getPosition(ticks[ticksPositions[2]]).x;

            this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.translate((tick1x - tick0x)/2)
        }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Hi @Nazar Ugrinovsky, You should be able to use `Highcharts` object in a render function. What is the result of `console.log(Highcharts)` ? Alternatively, you can call the method through a tick: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z2dp78en/

Comment: Thanks. I use a composition of two components. The first basic component works directly with the Highcharts and is a child of the wrapper. The wrapper generates data for the base component. The wrapper knows nothing about Highcharts.

Comment: Hi @Nazar Ugrinovsky, Could you reproduce that situation in some online code editor?